# Is it a problem to have packages with "amd64" architecture when I have an intel cpu?

Tags: package-management, cpu-architecture

I am trying to debug a scanner install failure and when checking if the required packages were present or not I saw a difference in the package architecture.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep Brother
ii  brscan-skey           0.2.4-1 amd64 Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4               0.4.2-1 amd64 Brother Scanner Driver
ii  mfcj6910dwcupswrapper 3.0.0-1 i386  Brother CUPS Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  mfcj6910dwlpr         3.0.0-1 i386  Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  printer-driver-ptouch 1.3-8   amd64 printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

Knowing I have an intel CPU (and also the printing is working + scanning failing) Do I need to replace the `amd64` packages with their `i386` equivalents?

Comment: There isn't any problems using amd64 on an Intel processor as It is fully compatible with the architecture.

Comment: @MichaelLindman thanks, so are you saying that the architectures are literally different , i.e. I thought `amd64` is 64bit and `i386` is 32bit, but despite that they are still compatible in certain situtations?

Comment: amd64 is 64-bit and i386 is 32-bit but you can use both architectures on an Intel or AMD processor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it will usually not cause any problems.

`amd64`, also known as x64, x86_64 and x86-64 refers to the 64-bit version of the x86 instruction set. It was developed by AMD (hence the name `amd64`) as an alternative to Intel's and HP's IA-64 architecture, as a means to add 64-bit computing capabilities to the existing x86 architecture.

Most recent Intel and AMD processors (with the exception of Intel's Itanium line) utilise the x86_64 architecture, so do not be confused by the name.

Comment: thanks, so are you saying that even though AMD developed the 64bit version of their `x86` instruction set as an different, alternative architecture to `IA-64`, they so in a way that was different, yet still actually compatible?

Comment: IA-64 and AMD64 are not compatible. IA-64 is Intel's Itanium server CPU architecture, while AMD64 is a 64-bit extension to Intel's x86 architecture. [This](http://superuser.com/questions/276994/difference-between-ia64-and-x64) might help you.

Comment: ok I think I got it `IA-64` is a special case for itanium CPU's otherwise for all other 64bit CPU's intel use the `x86_64` even though it was developed by AMD?

Comment: Yep, correct! Only Intel's Itanium line uses the IA-64 architecture.

Comment: Yeah, ia64 is a completely separate architecture, with no similarity to x86/i386, or to x86_64/amd64.

Comment: @user4668401  Intel licenses x86_64 from AMD so they are fully compatible, no separate development or random chance involved.

Answer (score 2):

AMD64 packages are for 64-bit processors and i386 are for 32-bit. `AMD64` and `i386` refers to the architecture, not the manufacturer.

To answer the question "*Is it a problem to have packages with “amd64” architecture when I have an intel cpu*?" - no, it isn't.

However, there may be some special cases when the amd64 package is known to have problems and the recommendation might be to install the i386 package instead.